# Compress heredoc declaration to one line in bash?

Tags: json, bash, heredoc

I have this which works to declare a JSON string in a bash script:

```
   local my_var="foobar"
   local json=`cat <<EOF
  {"quicklock":"${my_var}"}
EOF`
```

The above heredoc works, but I can't seem to format it any other way, it literally has to look exactly like that lol.

Is there any way to get the command to be on one line, something like this:

```
   local json=`cat <<EOF{"quicklock":"${my_var}"}EOF`
```

that would be so much nicer, but doesn't seem to take, obviously simply because that's not how EOF works I guess lol.

**I am looking for a shorthand way to declare JSON in a file that:**

1. Does not require a ton of escape chars.
2. That allows for dynamic interpolation of variables.

**Note:**  The actual JSON I want to use has multiple dynamic variables with many key/value pairs. Please extrapolate.

Comment: Why even bother with a here document for a single line? `json='{"quicklock":true}'`

Comment: This code seems overengineered. Why not just `json='{"quicklock":true}'`? Good luck.

Comment: @shellter you cannot put dynamic bash variables in your json with single quotes..declaring static json is not very useful.

Comment: I really had to spell it out for both of you I guess. I have variables that I need to include in the json.

Comment: `json="   {\"quicklock\":\"${my_var}\"}"`?

Comment: My 2 cents: `j='{"quicklock":"%s"}'; json=$(printf "$j" "${my_var}")`. With `printf` you can build your json skeleton and then fill it later.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz thanks, that might work for one variable but might be harder with more than 1?

Comment: @Cyrus yes that works, but having to escape all those characters is ugly and error prone

Comment: you guys might hate this, but before I discovered the heredoc solution, I was using this: https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/a4e3948b0ce9c22752c759d7e694c9ab

Comment: works for any # of vars `j='{"quicklock":"%s","slowlock":"%s"}'; json=$(printf "$j" "${my_var}" "${o_var}")`.

Comment: nice, you might like the linked solution in the github gist

Comment: BTW, this is a buggy way to generate JSON -- it won't correctly escape invalid characters; consider if `my_var='foo", "next_url": "http://evil.com/'` or such -- I've seen real-world APIs where that kind of thing results in adding malicious image links to notifications or the like. Use `jq` instead.

Comment: @Olegzandr, `json=$(jq -n --arg my_var "$my_var" '{"quicklock": $my_var}')`, by contrast, will honor your variable but *always* generate well-formed output. (If your variable is supposed to be well-formed JSON to start with, you can change that to `json=$(jq -n --arg my_var "$my_var" '{"quicklock": ($my_var | fromjson)}')`; the net effect is that you get an error if that value *isn't* JSON, rather than silently generating an invalid document).

Comment: @LuisMuñoz, ...the `printf` approach provides no protection against injection attacks. It's suitable for many purposes, but generating JSON or XML embedding untrusted data is not among them. (I'm using "untrusted" in the sense of NSA design guidelines: *"Trusted" components are ones that can break your system if they fail*; thus, a robust system trusts as little as possible).

Comment: @charles-duffy good point, honestly, never thought about bash security in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq)? It's pretty good at managing string interpolation and it lints your structure.

```
$ echo '{}' >> foo.json
$ declare myvar="assigned-var"
$ jq --arg ql "$myvar" '.quicklock=$ql' foo.json
```

the text that comes out on the other end of that call to jq can then be `cat` into a file or whatever you wanna do. text would look something like this:

```json
{"quicklock": "assigned-var"}
```

Comment: Missing some quotes; should be `--arg ql "$myvar"` so it works when the value has whitespace, glob characters, etc.

Comment: And `local` is only valid in a function; if you want code to work in other contexts while still making things local when used in a function, use `declare` instead.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a JSON guy, don't really understand the "well-formed" arguments in the discussion above, but, you can use a 'here-string' rather than a 'here-document', like this:

```
my_var="foobar"
json=`cat <<<{\"quicklock\":\"${my_var}\"}`
```

Comment: nice, one thing though was really hoping to avoid the escape chars, that was a big one

Comment: "well-formed", in this context, means "compliant with the JSON specification". Not all strings can be substituted unmodified into the template at hand while still ensuring that the result is valid JSON. Consider `my_var='"'` for a trivial example of a value for which this code will generate non-well-formed output -- the output would be `{"quicklock":"""}`, whereas it would *need* to be `{"quicklock":"\""}`. Similarly, for `my_var=$(printf '%s\n' "first line" "second line")`, valid output would be `{"quicklock":"first line\nsecond line"}`, but the *actual* output will have a literal newline.

Comment: btw, what is the `<<<` called? is there a name for it? trying to read about it

Comment: @Olegzandr, it's called a "here-string". See the "Here Strings" section of https://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument

Comment: @CharlesDuffy well for end-users, a herestring or heredoc is fine imo, the dev can be responsible for not putting in bad chars in a variable. On the other hand, If you are writing a library like `jq`, then no.

Comment: @Olegzandr, when you make your callers responsible for doing something right, you're spreading the responsibility around -- making more pieces that can break the system if they behave in a faulty way. That's not a good practice if your goal is to make something robust, *especially* when it's not obvious that quotes or newlines shouldn't be allowed in input.

Comment: Sure heredoc or herestring works, just check every variable for bad chars before interpolating them.

Comment: I mean, why should anyone think they *can't* run, say, `./your-notification-script "$(dump-logs | tail)"` without checking which characters are in that log first? And if the format of those log messages changes over time, an assumption that someone thinks is true at one time can become untrue later.

Comment: Right, the script will have to check each var for bad chars

Comment: @Olegzandr, ...that's my point -- if you did it right in the first place (and used `jq`), you wouldn't force all the other scripts to need to know what *constitutes* a "bad character", and have bugs if their attempts at knowing what was and wasn't a bad character were wrong.

Comment: This answer is good but does not meet the first criterion in the list in the OP.

Comment: The here-string is not needed at all. Since you want to store the string into variable, the assignment is sufficient in this case: `json2={\"quicklock\":\"${my_var}\"}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with printf:

```
local json="$(printf '{"quicklock":"%s"}' "$my_var")"
```

(Never mind that SO's syntax highlighting looks odd here.  Posix shell command substitution allows nesting one level of quotes.)

A note (thanks to [Charles Duffy's comment on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49951601/compress-heredoc-declaration-to-one-line-in-bash/50138270#comment87077602_49951601)): I'm assuming `$my_var` is not controlled by user input.  If it is, you'll need to be careful to ensure it is legal for a JSON string.  I highly recommend barring non-ASCII characters, double quotes, and backslashes.  If you have `jq` available, you can use it as Charles noted in the comments to ensure you have well-formed output.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own helper function to address the situation with missing [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) syntax:

```
function begin() { eval echo $(sed "${BASH_LINENO[0]}"'!d;s/.*begin \(.*\) end.*/\1/;s/"/\\\"/g' "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"); }
```

Then you can use it as follows.

```
my_var="foobar"

json=$(begin { "quicklock" : "${my_var}" } end)

echo "$json"
```

This fragment displays the desired output:

```
{ "quicklock" : "foobar" }
```

This is just a proof of concept. You can define your syntax in any way you want (such as end of the input by the custom EOF string, correctly escape invalid characters). For example, since Bash allows function identifiers using characters other than alphanumeric characters, it is possible to define such a syntax:

```
json=$(/ { "quicklock" : "${my_var}" } /)
```

Moreover, if you relax the first criterion (escape characters), ordinary assignment will nicely solve this problem:

```
json="{ \"quicklock\" : \"${my_var}\" }"
```

Comment: I can explain the helper function in detail if anyone interested.

Comment: this is pretty neat

Answer (score 0):

Since **no escape chars is strong requirement** here is a here-doc based solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

my_var='foobar'

read -r -d '' json << EOF
{
    "quicklock": "$my_var"
}
EOF

echo "$json"
```

It will give you the same output as the first solution I mentioned.

Just be careful, if you would put first `EOF` inside double quotes:

```
read -r -d '' json << "EOF"
```

`$my_var` would not be considered as a variable but as a plain text, so you would get this output:

```
{
        "quicklock": "$my_var"
}
```

Comment: yeah really want to avoid the need for escape chars, that's a big requirement, I should make that clear in the question. Heredoc allows you to avoid the standard escape chars.

Comment: thanks is the `read -d ''` solution x-platform? macos and linux?

Comment: It is bash builtin so it should work on any platform. I updated the example adding `-r` option to `read` since [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net) reported a warning.

Answer (score 0):

How about just using the shell's natural concatenation of strings? If you concatenate `${mybar}` rather than interpolate it, you can avoid escapes and get everything on one line:

```
my_var1="foobar"
my_var2="quux"
json='{"quicklock":"'${my_var1}'","slowlock":"'$my_var2'"}'
```

That said, this is a pretty crude scheme, and as others have pointed out you'll have problems if the variables, say, contain quote characters.